# What is the syntax for printing multiple data types in Python?

Tags: python, printing, syntax

If I have:

```
`my_float = 1.5`
`my_int = 1`
```

How do I print `"[float] is larger than [int]"` in Python?

Comment: Please refine your question, your question should be self-standing answerable without your own answer.

Comment: [pyformat.info/](https://pyformat.info/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example:

```
name = "Sven
age = 20
city = "a house"
print("Hello, your name is {name}, you are {age} years old and you live in {city}".format(name=name, age=age, city=city)
```

Will output:

```
Hello, your name is Sven, you are 20 years old and you live in a house.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val1 =  1.2
val2 = 2
print "%s is greater than %s"%(val2,val1)
```

This will print 
2 is greater than 1.2

```
val1 =  2.2
val2 = 2
print "%s is greater than %s"%(val1,val2)
```

2.2 is greater than 2