# how can i print a float and a string in the same line

Tags: python

I am working on a simple display for the result but when I try to put a string and the float is the same line i got an error.

here is the code:

```
num1 = input('Type a number: \n')
num2 = input('type second number: \n')
res = float(num1) + float(num2)
print('Your result is: ' + res)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the syntax for printing multiple data types in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36906268/what-is-the-syntax-for-printing-multiple-data-types-in-python)

Comment: The Zen of Python notwithstanding, there are several ways to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
print('Your result is: ' + str(res))
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
print("Hello World", 1.45)
```

For you

```
print('Your result is:', res)
```